# What is significance of amp_lite parameter in AMP-HTML pages

Tags: amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

On a lot of AMP pages, I see visitors are directed through apparently different version of AMP-html - `https://amp-html-url/?amp_lite`

I'm curious, what is the significance of this **`amp_lite`** parameter. What is the difference between normal amp-html and the `?amp_lite` amp-html version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may refer with this [blog](https://seoheronews.com/google-amp-lite). It stated that this was a code name for a project to make AMP better for slow networks but many readers interpreted this as a separate version of AMP.

The result of the article in this format is loaded faster than the standard AMP. Because it reduce the size of the page in the AMP Lite and due to the compression of the images and their data.